# What does "I will let you get back to work" mean in terms of tone?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the common hall of my office, in America, after some brief small talk, I said to my colleague,

> OK, I will let you get back to work.

She did something really unusual upon hearing it: she did not say anything, but she moved another chair with her leg. I interpret it as "Come, sit". I took the seat, and talked to her for another 10 minutes.

I want to know if this phrase sounds weird/unusual to a native English speaker?

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion, tone, and circumstances. It could be taken as implying that the person is lazy or should be working, but it could a sincere apology for taking someone from their work. If a manager says it, it quite likely means "I'm done talking to you, now get to work!" Grammatically it's fine though.

Comment: [At my office or in my office.]  We cannot decipher tone without actually hearing the tone you used. We can't tell if you are the subordinate or that person is. So which is it and what happened?

Comment: I think the combination of my answer and Michael Harvey's comment under my answer would be a clue to the behavior.  The locution is a polite acknowledgement, tinged with humility on the part of the speaker, that the other person's time is valuable and you do not wish to infringe upon it.  Of course it could be said in a perfunctory manner that would rob it of those nuances. Apparently it wasn't :-)

Comment: @TimR Without hearing the tone, we **cannot know the tone** regardless of what usual meaning is. I can't even understand myself why she said it.

Comment: @Lambie Did you even read what I wrote?  Also, *she* didn't say anything. She moved a chair with her leg which appears to have been an invitation to sit.

Comment: @TimR Yes, and I completely disagree with you as you describe it:  is to know what it is: **you have to hear it**. This is tone as in tone and intonation. Not some meta-level of the idea of tone.

Comment: @Max - I'd say, crack on, mate!

Comment: Now it's starting to become clear. There is NOTHING inherently untoward in what you said. Why do you think it was even a problem? let is causative, not lexical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal meaning of "I'll let you X" in a context like this is "*I'll stop taking up your time, which will allow you to X*", and as TimR has already explained in his answer, it can have the function of expressing a *mild apology* for disturbing someone.

There is another function not mentioned yet, which is to *politely excuse yourself* from an interaction, place, event, etc., and really has nothing to do with whether you're disturbing the other person or not.

For instance, at the end of a long phone conversation with a friend or family member, one of us often says, "Well, I'll let you go now", which actually means, "I'm ready to stop talking".

In your situation, your coworker wanted to continue talking with you so much that she disregarded your polite excuse to leave the conversation, and invited you to stay longer. This is somewhat uncommon for a peer to do, so it likely indicates that she enjoys your company and might be flirting with you.

IMO, you did nothing unusual at all.

Answer (score 0):

Typically "I will let you get back to ... {whatever}" is a very mild apology for having bothered the person and taken up their time. It could be paraphrased as "I don't want to take up any more of your valuable time than I already have; I'm sure you are busy and have more important things to do than answer my questions".

Despite **let**, there is no implication that the speaker is in a position to control the person's activities and decide what they do and when.

Comment: It could very easily be construed as a polite ending, like 'I'll let you get on with your day'.

Comment: Yes, for sure.  Nothing to take umbrage at.

Comment: Regardless of meaning, we can't hear her tone. That's the real point here.

Comment: @Lambie The word **tone** has more than one meaning in a language context. Locutions themselves can have an abstract "tone of voice" that is independent of the delivery of the speaker, independent of the audible qualities of their voice. Abstract tone is established in part by the connotations of the locution, the contexts in which it is typically used, its register, and so on.

Comment: Come on, tone is tone in spoken language. Abstract tone, really? For an actual utterance?

Comment: @Lambie   You're like a guy in Plato's cave telling a guy who is outside the cave what is going on outside the cave, based on the shadows you see on the wall inside the cave.

Comment: You can quote 101 philosophy to me all you want but your understanding of tone in this context is contrived. An utterance has no inherent tone, even "please" and "thank you". The point is they are shadows and if you are not in the cave with the other guy, you won't see 'em (to try and use your reference).

Comment: @Lambie: OP is not asking about the *manner* in which he said it aloud it but about its *intrinsic* tone.  He was there and said the words and doesn't need to ask us about *how* he said it.  He's not asking if his tone of voice was too harsh, or curt, or blasé, whatever.

Comment: Nope, he says in terms of tone. And I am saying if we were not there, we don't know. This discussion is pointless.

Comment: Discussing it with you is pointless.

Comment: Sorry @Lambie, I'm on TimR's side in this—or rather on both your sides. True, you can alter *any* language through delivery, or context. "I'll let you get back to your work," delivered with malicious glee by an evil torturer to an imprisoned captive, is sarcasm. From a big-eyed toddler it can be either heartwarming or guilt-inducing. But meanwhile, we do talk about written tone. And even at their most context-agnostic, certain phrasings have impact. E.g., I was going to tell the OP that skipping the contraction "I'll" would itself have a distancing effect.

Comment: @Lambie And—assuming vocal and contextual "tone" to be neutral—choosing between "I'll let you get back to your work," "I've taken up enough of your time," and "I'm done talking to you" all have different tones, just from the superficial text chosen. Your point is valid, that we can't know the ultimate *effect* without having been there, but it's reasonable of the OP to ask about the generic effect.

Comment: @AndyBonner Not the ultimate effect, just the effect. There is only generic meaning of that "idiom." I really do not need either of you to explain tone to me. Come on. It's baby stuff here. This is not a literature course, is it?

Comment: @Max I would add to this, as an idiomatic practice, "I'll let you get back to [something]" is also a common euphemistic way to voluntarily end a conversation. It might actually be that *you're* eager to get back to work, or simply to escape the conversation, but you're casting it as doing a favor to the other person. This simple "social lie" is usually recognized as such, but also as a signal that you want to end the conversation, and the other person will usually go along with it. It's odd that your coworker did the opposite, at least without saying anything extra.

Comment: @Lambie Easy there; I don't think this question or this answer needs to be particularly controversial. Basics is kind of what this SE covers.

Comment: @AndyBonner I objected to the long-winded answer given. See abstract tone above. Think of this: one can say the sentence and be utterly sarcastic, right? Or even aggressive right? Or funny? Or whimsical. etc. etc. etc.  That said, we cannot know., We were not there and he has no recording of it. But in and of itself it's just one polite expression with causative let to take one's leave from someone else. And there is no written tone here as it was **spoken** so why even complicate it when the person ain't even understood (maybe), the basic idiom??

Comment: @Lambie: You continue to overlook the fact that the questioner is not asking about his tone but about the tone of the construction -- what I've called its "abstract" tone--connotation, register, usual contexts.  If I asked "Was it OK for me to ask the pope *How's it hangin?*  or was that **tone** too casual?" would you follow the same tack and say "We weren't there to hear your tone, so discussing your question is pointless" ?   No, you wouldn't.